# Скриншот в двумерный массив

Tags: c#, массивы, .net, screenshots

Мне надо сделать скриншот и записать в массив пикселей (представив их как числа).

Погуглив, я написал вот такой код:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

static class Screenshot
{   
    public static byte[] Take(Rectangle area)
    {
        using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(area.Width, area.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
        {
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(area.Location, Point.Empty, bitmap.Size, System.Drawing.CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream)
                {
                    bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Однако у него две проблемы:

Первая: полученный массив - это не пиксели, это как бы файл в bmp-формате, с заголовком.

Вторая: массив одномерный.

В принципе, ни одна из проблем не является критической, можно ведь организовать чтение байт, рассчитывая положение по координатам пикселя и делая поправку на заголовок (62 байта, вроде бы).
Но может, все же есть простой способ получить массив цветов в виде двумерного массива размерностью [width, heigth], а не одномерного размерностью [62 + width * height * 4]?

Answer (score 1):

```
var b = new Bitmap(@"C:\Temp\1.jpg");
var d = b.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, 
            b.PixelFormat);
var length = Math.Abs(d.Stride) * b.Height;
var rgbs = new byte[length];
Marshal.Copy(d.Scan0, rgbs, 0, length);
```

Comment: Великая и ужасная либа Маршал! Я бы лет 5 назад в цикле сделал =)